# My Jquery file cant find Controller In laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, controller

I'm trying to pass data from the view to my controller, but I cant make it work, I have used the same sintaxe in CodeIgniter and it worked really well! Ant help?

```
function Navigation() {
    $(".getDataId").on("click", function(){
        var dataId = $(this).attr("data-id");
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://localhost/test/test/nav',
            data: {DataId: dataId},
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("success");
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(response){
                console.log("error");
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And when I log the data it gives me object Object

The response is quite big but it outputs me this:

```
> {\n    \"message\": \"\",\n    \"exception\":
> \"Symfony\\\\Component\\\\HttpKernel\\\\Exception\\\\NotFoundHttpException\",\n
> \"file\":
> \"C:\\\\wamp64\\\\www\\\\Simples\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\RouteCollection.php\",\n
> \"line\": 179,\n
```

UPDATE:

Here is my routing: 
I didnt quite understand it yet!

```
Route::get('/', 'test@index');
```

In my Controller the index function gets some data from the db and sends it to the view with a : `return view`.

Comment: And can you share your route from the `web.php` file?

Comment: @nakov Just updated the post! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter and Laravel are two different framework. 
In codeigniter you do not need to define route first for any http request .
But in laravel you must define each request you want to make in your web.php file.

Comment: Yes that is what I'm learning but I didnt quite get it yet! Moving and learning! I updated the post and put my route, any help would be apreciated!